# Custom iteration through array in C printing every nth value

Tags: c, arrays, loops, iteration

I'm currently working on a homework assignment and what I have to do is ask for the size of the array and what I would like to loop through it (how many things I should skip through). Example (I bolded what would be the users response)

How large is the array?
**10**

How would you like to iterate through it?
**3**

Conditions:

Then it should loop through every third item and then start over looping through the items that haven't been picked until the last one. I must also start on the first item (0) which you can see in my code that I provided.

---

This is what I thought I could do...

```
int amount=0, often=0, counter=0, x;

printf("Size of Array? ");
scanf("%d", &amount);
printf("iteration size? ");
scanf("%d", &often);

// sets the array (1 means it exists)
int[] array[amount];
for(x=0; x<amount; x++)
    array[x] = 1;

// the part that I'm confused on
// supposed to iterate through everything
for(x=0; x<amount; x++){
    if(array[0] == 1){
        printf("#0\n");
        array[0]=0;
    }
    if(array[x]==1)
        counter++;
    if(counter == often){
        printf("#%d\n", x);
        array[x]=0;
        counter=0;
    }
return 0;
}
```

However, I need to continuously loop through until the entire array is done except for the last one. Mine stops after I loop through the array once. This is the output I have verse the output I want.

> My output:
>
> 0
>
> 3
>
> 6
>
> 9
>
> Wanted output:
>
> 0
>
> 3
>
> 6
>
> 9
>
> 4
>
> 8
>
> 5
>
> 2
>
> 7

**Notice how the the wanted output loops through it again picking the third number that hasn't been picked yet.** That is where I'm confused and how to fix this problem. Any guidance or information would be great, thanks.

Comment: You must specify the size of the array using a constant value. `int array[256]` should be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: Are you sure that's what the output should be? From the description, I would have expected 0,3,6,9,1,4,7,2,5,8 or 0,3,6,9,2,5,8,1,4,7.

Comment: I would go for the easy way. During loop realloc all the time another array like this:
Each iteration ( step ONLY by ONE, no matter, what the user chose ) can modulo-divide the integer at the current position by the chosen iterator. If modulo is 0, the printf can be issued, if it is set, realloc the other array and put the numbers in between into this new array. The second loop would loop over the new array and print only those, which could not have been divided by the chosen iterator without rest. Voila.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: C99 allows variable-length arrays. There is a syntax error in the line (the empty `[]` should not be there) but only archaic compilers do not allow you to use a VLA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep looping until all numbers have been printed,
for instance like this:

```
int total = amount;
counter = often - 1;
while (total > 0) {
    for(x=0; x<amount; x++){
        if(array[x]==1)
            counter++;
        if(counter == often){
            printf("#%d\n", x);
            array[x]=0;
            counter=0;
            total--;
        }    
    }
}
```

**Edit: The entire program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  int amount=0, often=0, counter=0, x;

  printf("Size of Array? ");
  scanf("%d", &amount);
  printf("iteration size? ");
  scanf("%d", &often);

  // sets the array (1 means it exists)
  int array[amount];  // Fixed typo in declaration
  for(x=0; x<amount; x++)
    array[x] = 1;

  // the part that I'm confused on
  // supposed to iterate through everything
  int total = amount;
  counter = often - 1;
  while (total > 0) {
    for(x=0; x<amount; x++){
      if(array[x]==1)
        counter++;
      if(counter == often){
        printf("#%d\n", x);
        array[x]=0;
        counter=0;
        total--;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Wall a.c -o a
```

Running the program:

```
Size of Array? 10
iteration size? 3
#0
#3
#6
#9
#4
#8
#5
#2
#7
#1
```

Comment: It works for me. Compare your version to mine and see if there is any difference.

Comment: How does this work with values 10 and 2, or 10 and 4?  If the size and step are not mutually prime (if GCD(size, step) is not 1), you have extra work to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The algorithm is to print every nth of the *remaining* numbers. When you get to the highest number you just continue from the lowest remaining number *without resetting the current count*. The algorithm works for any positive integers that fit in the chosen type.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start out with a loop which skips every three numbers:

```
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i += 3)
{
    print(i);

    array[i] = 0;
}
```

Now, this only seems to work for 0, 3, 6, 9.

We want to be able to start at the first existing value, and repeat this process until nothing remains.

So let's put another loop on the outside, to count how many items remain:

```
int total = amount;

while(total > 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i += 3)
    {
        print(i);

        array[i] = 0;
        total--;
    }
}
```

Good so far, but we still start at 0 every time. We want to start at a particular value, and skip until the 3rd number is reached.

```
int total = amount;

while(total > 0)
{
    for(int i = getStartingIndex(array, 3); i < amount; i += 3)
    {
        while(array[i] == 0 && i < amount)
            i++;

        print(i);

        array[i] = 0;
        total--;
    }
}
```

Let's define our `getStartingIndex` function:

```
int getStartingIndex(int array[], int skipCount)
{
    int index = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < skipCount; i++)
    {
        while(array[index] == 0)
            index++;

        index++;
    }

    return index - 1;
}
```

Now, we start at the value specified, and print numbers until we reach `amount`. And then we go back to the beginning, but we start at the third unused number.

Comment: It looks like this will give 0369147258, as opposed to 036948527 as listed in the post.  Reading the post again, it looks like this order is a requirement.

Comment: Ah, the third number that hasn't been picked yet! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We need to keep the current step size, it will run from zero to the desired step size and each time we visit an index and mark it as visited we will reset that counter to zero. Our main loop will iterate over the array one by one, until there are no unvisited indices left. We make sure the index does not run out of bounds of the array, so when index hits the length of the array, we reset it to zero.

If you don't want the last element to be printed, just change the while loop's conditional to `while (visited_count < total_length - 1)`

```
int main() {
    int array[10] = { 0 };
    int total_length = 10;
    int visited_count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int step_size = 3;
    int current_step = 3;
    while (visited_count != total_length) /* while there are unvisited elements */
    {
        if (!array[index] && current_step == step_size) /* array[index] has value zero, and we are at the desired step count, so print that element and mark it as visited */
        {
            array[index] = 1;
            visited_count++;
            printf("%d\n", index);
            current_step = 0; /* resetting the step counter */
        }
        index++; /* this is how we iterate over the array, incrementing it at each iteration */
        if (index == total_length) /* checking for out-of-bounds of the array, if we hit the total length, the index should be reset. */
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        if (!array[index]) /* now that we have stepped through the array, we increment the step counter if that element is not visited. */
        {
            current_step++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```